# Can't receive response for JsonObjectRequest on some public WiFi networks - how do I work around this?

Tags: android, android-volley

I'm writing an Android app which needs to make some HTTP requests - specifically, I'm using the Volley library to make a JsonObjectRequest. This works fine on my home WiFi network and on 4G.

However, I attempted to test this today while at a Starbucks, and it looks like I'm never receiving a response. (No error code - just no response received). Does anyone know why this might be happening or how to work around it? It'd be a huge pain if my users couldn't reliably get the app to work on some WiFi networks.

For what its worth, the JSON Object that should be arriving in response is extremely large.

EDIT: I'm attempting to replicate this issue, and getting a 50-50 'success' rate. It works flawlessly on 4G every time, but on the Starbucks Wi-Fi is a toss-up. Any ideas why? The network isn't particularly slow or patchy.

Comment: are you actually signed up at the starbucks' wifi?

Comment: is it http or https?

Comment: It is http and I am signed up

Comment: I would suggest to use https. In that case, you could not receive a response that does not come from your server, so it would be reliable.